# Detect GZIP compression in HTTP Module

Tags: c#, gzip, httpmodule

How can I detect whether or not GZIP is enabled for a particular request in my HTTP Module? I apply a filter to the output, and when it acts on gzipped content, it screws up the compression somehow, and the client browser throws an error that it can't decode the content.

```
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        // if(HttpContext.Current.IsCompressed) // Check for compressed content here            

        // Set up the filter / replacement.
        context.PostReleaseRequestState += (_, __) =>
        {
            var filterStream = new ResponseFilterStream(HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter);
            filterStream.TransformString += FilterPage;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter = filterStream;
        };
    }
```

`ResponseFilterStream` is a custom stream which caches all stream writes and presents the contents as an event in order to allow a method to modify the contents of the stream. It works great for modifying HTML requests (which is what I want), but I don't want it to act on gzip-compressed responses. How can I detect a gzipped response and prevent the filter stream from being hooked up to the response?

Comment: Something like `if (response.Filter is System.IO.Compression.GZipStream)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a response, you can check the `Encoding` http header for a value of `gzip` or `deflate`

For a request, you need to check `Accept-Encoding` http header for a value of `gzip` or `deflate` encoding.

[HTTP Compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression)

Comment: Just tried this, it works, but I had to use `Content-Encoding` for the response.